# Can't save output in the script mode

Tags: export, files-and-directories, scripting, command-line

I encounter the problem that I can't save any output from Mathematica script. Here is a minimal example.

test.m

```
Export["/home/my_home_folder/file.txt", "hello world"]
```

I run the script with

```
math -script test.m
```

and the output file is not produced. Instead of `math` I've also tried `MathematicaScript` and `wolframscript -f test.m`, they hadn't work either.

Interactively, i.e. running `math` from the terminal and executing the same `Export` command, everything works just fine. 
I run the script remotely using ssh on a Linux machine.

Is there a way to fix this or any alternative way of saving the data from the script mode?

**EDIT**.

OK, I resolved the problem and it was pretty dumb. I used Mathematica as an editor and my cells was of the "Input" type, but it should have been of the "Code" type, otherwise, it doesn't work.

Here is the non-working version of the code as it is viewed by Notepad:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Input:: *)
(*Export["/home/my_home_folder/file.txt","hello world"]*)
```

And here is the working one:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Code:: *)
(*Export["/home/my_home_folder/file.txt","hello world"]*)
```

Comment: Try `math -run "<<test.m"`

Comment: @MannyC , thanks! It doesn't work though. With this command, an interactive session is opened, as if it was just `math`

Comment: If you want it to exit later you can do `math -run "<<test.m;Quit[]"`

Comment: @MannyC OK, I see. The problem is, however, that the output file is still not produced. Interactively everything works, but I'd like to do some scripting and potentially submit a job to a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I usually do for scripting (this works in a cluster too). Say I want to write script that depends on one argument. Then I define `script.m` to be

```
cmds=Drop[$CommandLine,3];

param = cmds[[1]];

(*Do stuff with param*)
result = param;
path = "/path/to/my/folder/result.txt";
(*End of stuff*)

Export[path, result];
WriteString["stdout", "Results exported to "<>path<>"\n"];

Quit[];
```

Then if you call it with

```
math -run "<<script.m" "Write this!"
```

It will write `Write this!` to the file `/path/to/my/file/result.txt`. This works fine for me, even on a cluster. Recall that when a job gets evaluated on a cluster, it's evaluated on a machine different from the login node. So `Directory[]` will give a different output.

Also, in most clusters you can redirect `stdout` to some file. In slurm for example you have to set up

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --chdir=/path/to/my/folder
#<Possibly other options>
#...

math -run "<<script.m" "Write this!"
```

But you may have a different cluster manager.

Comment: Thank you for your extended answer! I kept trying and finally resolved the problem. It was really stupid (see the edit).